# Ball and geodesics in a riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a *riemannian manifold*. Let $S \subset M$ be a *compact submanifold with corners* and $p \in M$ a point belonging to $\partial A$. Can we ensure that exists $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ (depending on $p$) such that for every $q \in B(p,\varepsilon)\cap S$ and $0 \leq t \leq \delta$ it is satisfied
$$
\exp_p(t\exp_{p}^{-1}(q)) \in S \cap B(p,\varepsilon)?
$$

I know that if $p \in \operatorname{int}(S)$ the result is obvious. If $S$ is locally convex the result is obvious too. Although, I was drawing some polyhedras in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and I thought that it is true in a this context too. Anyone can help me?

PS. I've just realized that the condition that I'm asking is: *are compact submanifold with corners locally star-shaped?*

Comment: Presumably $A=S$?

Comment: Yes, sorry :). I edit it

Comment: there are some other things you may want to fix. I assume $x= p$? Are you assuming that $q\in S$? And is $\exp$ the exponentional map or $M$, or of $S$? If I look at the northern half of the $n-1$ dimensional sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which does not even have corners) I wonder why such a result should be true, anyway?

Comment: What about $S=[-1,1]^2$ in $M=\Bbb R^2$, $p = (0,1)$, $q = (0,1+\varepsilon/2)$? In that case, $\exp_p(tv) = p + tv$, to that $\exp_p(t\exp^{-1}(q)) = p+t(0,\varepsilon/2)$, which is never in $S$ for $t>0$.

Comment: The example it not valid because I said $q \in B(p,\varepsilon) \cap S$. Your example, in fact, has the property that I want to prove. It is a very interesting question and I can't find anything about it.

Comment: The other cuestion, yes, $x = p$, I have changed it.

Comment: @JulianDoyle No you didn't say it. You just edited the question! These crucial information were missing.

Comment: Yes, but it was a typo, the «condition locally star-shaped» implies this...

Comment: @JulianDoyle Accumulation of typos makes the question hardly readable, even with some minor precisions in the last sentences

Answer (score 1):

Consider $M=\Bbb R^2$ endowed with the euclidean metric, and
$$
S = \left\{(x,y) \in M \mid x\in [-1,1] \quad \text{and}  \quad 0\leqslant y \leqslant 1 + x^2\right\}.
$$

$S$ is a compact submanifold with corners (the corners are $(\pm 1,0)$ and $(\pm 1,2)$).
Let $p= (0,1)\in S$, and $q = (x,1+x^2)\in S$ for some $x\in [-1,1]$.
By strict convexity of the function $f(x) = 1+x^2$, we have
$$
S \cap [p,q] = \{p,q\}.
$$
From this, it should be clear that the statement you wish to be true is false.